# How to do data search in dataset with Python Django

Tags: python, django, search

I am new to Django and I'm working on dataset search.

Given this

```
class Student(models.Model):
  score_1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  score_2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I know how get the students with the score_1 higher than 90, which is something like this:

```
s = Student.objects.filter(score_1__gte=90)
```

However, I'm having problem getting the students who have their score_1 10 points more than their score_2, aka score_1 - score_2 >= 10.

Since there are lots of student data, I cannot just pull all the data out and then do the search, which will apparently take forever. So is there any other way to do this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) to use model fields in filter:

```
from django.db.models import F
s = Student.objects.filter(score_1__gte=F('score2') + 10)
```